# Laravel redirect with errormessagebag not returning the actual message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-response

I started a new laravel 8 project and installed the laravel breeze auth starter kit. After that i made an api endpoint and i want to validate the post request going to that endpoint so i wrote some code:

```php
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'project_name' => 'required',
            'project_location' => 'required',
            'project_tasks' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('project_error', $validation->errors());
        }
```

But when i print out

```php
{{ dump(Session::get('project_error') }}
```

its empty, so i solved it by adding the following

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

to **protected $middleware** in **App/Http/Kernel.php**
That solves the issue but then my breeze starter kit login does not return a response when i enter the wrong details and it logs me out when i make an post request to the project api endpoint.

breeze auth code:

```php
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        if (!Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }
```

Does anyone know how i can still have the breeze auth response and the **return redirect()->back()->with('project_error', $validation->errors());** at the same time.

I hope i provided enough info :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do `throw ValidationException::withMessages(...)` and the routing engine should handle the redirect back.

Comment: But really you should be using form request validation and not doing this manually. Validation in controller is outdated these days.

Comment: @miken32 i tried the ``throw validationexception`` but that does also not print anything when i do @foreach($errors->all() as $error) {{$error}}, and what do u exactly mean by: 'But really you should be using form request validation'?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: if its an "api" end point in `routes/api.php` there are no sessions, that is for stateless apis ... move your route to the `web.php` file if you want sessions ... the routes in `web.php` have the `web` group of middleware applied (which includes `StartSession` so you can have sessions) ... if you are not planning on having a stateless API then you could adjust the middleware for `routes/api.php` to use `web` instead of the `api` group .... then the routes in `web.php` and `api.php` would act the same